# How do I prove this recursive sequence converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$a_1=2$, and $a_{n+1}=\frac{2a_n +3}{a_n +2}$. I'm not sure on how to prove this by mathematical induction it's my weak point.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Comment: Note that $a_{n+1}=\frac{2a_n+3}{a_n+2}=2-\frac{1}{a_n+2}$

Comment: So where do I go from there?

Comment: Decreasing, clearly bounded below, so converges.

Comment: I understand it's decreasing but they want proofs etc which I really don't get

Comment: @vrugtehagel I saw that as a comment to the edit you wrote: "Use Mathjax!". You are supposed to write an edit summary there, so the people reviewing your edit get an indication of what you did. Furthermore, in this case the OP clearly is a new user. A phrase like: "Use Mathjax!" is then not very constructive and IMHO quite rude (in general). It would be better if you kindly give a new user some advice on how this site works. For this you can post a comment. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4925/145141) you can find some comment templates that might be useful in situations like this.

Comment: @gebruiker, thank you. I'll be more explicit, and less rude, in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Tip: first find the limit **if it exists**, then prove that that limit is actually correct.

If the limit is $L$ we have
$$L=\frac{2L+3}{L+2}\ ,\quad L\ge0\ ,$$
which can be solved to give $L=\sqrt3$.  Now it is easy to see that $a_n$ is always positive, so we have
$$\eqalign{\left|a_{n+1}-\sqrt3\right|
  &=\left|\frac{2a_n+3}{a_n+2}-\sqrt3\right|\cr
  &=\left|\frac{(2-\sqrt3)a_n+(3-2\sqrt3)}{a_n+2}\right|\cr
  &=\frac{2-\sqrt3}{a_n+2}\left|a_n-\sqrt3\right|\cr
  &<\Bigl(\frac{2-\sqrt3}{2}\Bigr)\left|a_n-\sqrt3\right|\ .\cr}$$
Since $\frac{2-\sqrt3}{2}<1$ we have $|a_n-\sqrt3|\to0$ and so $a_n\to\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following induction step.

Suppose that for a certain $k$ we have $a_{k+1}\lt a_k$. We show that $a_{k+2}\lt a_{k+1}$. Because $a_{k+1}\lt a_k$, we have $\frac{1}{a_{k+1}+2}\gt\frac{1}{a_k+2}$. And now
$$a_{k+2}=2-\frac{1}{a_{k+1}+2}\lt 2-\frac{1}{a_k+2}=a_{k+1}.$$

Our sequence is decreasing, and bounded below, since $0$ is a lower bound. It follows that the sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a_k=\frac{p_k}{q_k}$ where one has one degree of freedom in the relation of $p_k$ and $q_k$. Then
$$
\frac{p_{k+1}}{q_{k+1}}=\frac{2p_k+3q_k}{p_k+2q_k}
$$
suggesting the linear recursion
$$
\begin{bmatrix}p_{k+1}\\q_{k+1}\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\1&2\end{bmatrix}
·
\begin{bmatrix}p_k\\q_k\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $p_1=2$ and $q_1=1$. Now the system matrix has the characteristic equation
$$
0=(λ-2)^2-3
$$
and thus eigenvalues $λ=2\pm\sqrt3$ with eigenvectors 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}p_\pm\\q_\pm\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}\pm\sqrt3\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Solving for the coefficients in
$$
\begin{bmatrix}p_k\\q_k\end{bmatrix}
=
c_+\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt3\\1\end{bmatrix}(2+\sqrt3)^k
+
c_-\begin{bmatrix}-\sqrt3\\1\end{bmatrix}(2-\sqrt3)^k
$$
gives the complete solution. However, the limit of $\frac{p_k}{q_k}$ is independent of the coefficients as long as $c_+\ne 0$, since then the fraction is dominated by the terms with $(2+\sqrt3)^k$, which gives the limit as 
$$
\lim_{k\to∞} a_k=\lim_{k\to∞}\frac{p_k}{q_k}
=\lim_{k\to∞} \frac{c_+p_++c_-p_-(2-\sqrt3)^{2k}}{c_+q_++c_-q_-(2-\sqrt3)^{2k}}
= \frac{p_+}{q_+}=\sqrt3.
$$